# Как отсортировать словарь по убыванию?

Tags: python, сортировка, словарь

Есть словарь:

```
users_database = {
'609629735': {'balance': 1, 'full_name': 'Anonymous Anonymously'}, 
'639141904': {'balance': 32, 'full_name': ''}
}
```

Как его можно отсортировать по убыванию значения в 'balance'?

Мне необходимо получить:

```
users_database = {
'639141904': {'balance': 32, 'full_name': ''}, 
'609629735': {'balance': 1, 'full_name': 'Anonymous Anonymously'}
}
```

Пару примеров, которыми я пытался получить необходимый результат:

```
users_database = {k: users_database[k]['balance'] for k in sorted(users_database, key=users_database.get('balance'), reverse=True)}
```

и

```
users_database = sorted(users_database, key=lambda x: int(x['balance']))
```

Прошу оставить читаемый и понятный код, который можно будет самостоятельно разобрать и понять что к чему, иные идеи / предложения / коды прошу оставлять в качестве комментария на этот вопрос.

Comment: Хотя сама задаче не очень правильно поставлена. Словарь не во всех версиях питона гарантирует порядок ключей. Лучше сортировать список ключей нужным образом, а потом по этим сортированным ключам уже выбирать из словаря данные. Как именно сортирует и хранит данные внутри себя словарь, в каком конкретном порядке - это должно быть неважно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для сортировки данных в Python используют встроенную функцию [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
res = dict(sorted(users_database.items(), 
                  key=lambda x: x[1].get("balance"), 
                  reverse=True))
```

результат:

```
In [281]: res
Out[281]:
{'639141904': {'balance': 32, 'full_name': ''},
 '609629735': {'balance': 1, 'full_name': 'Anonymous Anonymously'}}
```